# Karate remove space from the response xpath

Tags: karate

- And match response/Address/Name/FirstName == firstName

I am taking the 'firstName' from the example. My response for xpath is having a space in front
actual: ' Tony', expected: 'Tony'

1. How to remove that in feature file . Is there sunction like trim().
2. Also Print 'response/Address/Name/FirstName' is not printing any value. How to get the response value printed from feature file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `contains`. Or yes, you can do a `trim()`

```
* def bar = 'bar'
* def foo = ' bar'
* match foo contains bar
* def foo = foo.trim()
* match foo == bar
```

Comment: @Sumith I don't understand. so improve your question or follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: I tried getting that response value from XML in to variable and then trim  by using below but didn't worked. How to assign a value from xpath to variable in feature file
 *def name='response/Address/Name/FirstNam'
 *def name="response/Address/Name/FirstNam"
 *def name=response/Address/Name/FirstNam

Also tried below but didnit worked

And match (response/Address/Name/FirstNam).trim() == myName
And match ('response/Address/Name/FirstNam').trim() == myName
And match ("response/Address/Name/FirstNam").trim() == myName
And match response/Address/Name/FirstNam.trim() == myName

Comment: @Sumith you can edit your question. posting all this is of no use, please create a SIMPLE sample XML that shows the example, also read up on how to format code in Stack Overflow. try again

Comment: <Response >
 <Address>
  <Name>
   <FirstName> John</FirstName>
   <LastName>Hon</LastName>
  </Name>
 </Address>
    </Response>  To trim() the space in Response/Address/Name/FirstName, How do I get the vale of this path to a variable

Comment: @Sumith I give up, all the best

Comment: Sorry I am new to posting in stackoverflow.  I tried formatting unfortunately didn't worked for my last comment. Thank you I got the answer I forget to use 'get ' in front of the path

Comment: @Sumith I mean you can go and edit your ORIGINAL question and there are many formatting options. please do that next time